# Owin autorization 3.0 - the error OpenID2 for Google accounts is going away

Tags: asp.net-mvc, owin, google-openid

I have mvc 5 and using owin 3.0 autorization. I start see the errors when tring loggin on facebook and google.

[image: facebook message]
[image: google message]

If I use last version of owin middleware for Google and Facebook will it work after those dates?